# Is there any way to recieve sensor events when app is closed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, alarmmanager, android-workmanager

I am new to flutter and working on the women safety app. I am doing this for the community's help and to make my society safe for everyone. I want to receive event updates when my app is closed and wandering if there is any way to do this in flutter. Specifically, I want to listen to shake events and run a specific code.

Use Case: For example, an app user feels uncomfortable or is in danger. She will shake her phone rapidly and the app will detect the shake and send the SOS alert. Regardless of the running state of the app.

I have used Work-manager and android_alarm_manager_plus plugins to listen to events. But they have limitations for time. Work-manager can be triggered only after 15 minutes and alarm_manager can trigger after 1 minute. I want to listen to shake events all the time. Please let me know if it is possible or not.

Another possible solution can be putting a menu tray in the notification panel and by clicking it the app will send a notification. I searched for this scenario but found nothing. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can using:

1. flutter_background_service
2. shake

Step 1: using Shake:

```
ShakeDetector detector = ShakeDetector.autoStart(
onPhoneShake: () {
            // Do stuff on phone shake
}
);
```

Step 2: custom flutter background service:

```
final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
service.onDataReceived.listen((event) {
if (event!["action"] == "setAsForeground") {
  service.setForegroundMode(true);
  return;
}

if (event["action"] == "setAsBackground") {
  service.setForegroundMode(false);
}

if (event["action"] == "stopService") {
  service.stopBackgroundService();
}
});
```